# Py2Exe, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'numpy-atlas.dll'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, py2exe

I have included matplotlib in my program, I searched about numpy_atlas.dll on google and I seem to be the only one on Earth with this problem.

## setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['EulerMethod.py'])
```

## Running Py2Exe results in error

```
C:\(..obmitted..)>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
*** parsing results ***
......
...obmitted...
......
*** finding dlls needed ***
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'numpy-atlas.dll'
```

Comment: This problem arose for me when I re-installed python. Prior to that, my script was working perfectly fine. I found the file at C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core, but py2exe can't find it for some reason. Previously, I was using python(x,y) but I switched to Anaconda (still python 2.7.x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like py2exe can't find dll. Following script will make py2exe quiet:

```
distutils.core.setup(
options = {
    "py2exe": {
        "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"]
    }
},
...
```

)

You still need to make sure that dll is on the user's machine. I believe numpy-atlas.dll is one of matplot dependencies.

Also consider using PyInstaller if everything else fails.

Comment: Do you know how I can bundle the exe so that all doll dependencies are included?

Comment: .dll's should be located in the dist directory along side the executable.

Comment: I haven't tried your solution yet, I'll make sure to try it and choose your answer if it works.

Comment: I have no idea if your answer works but PyInstaller is absolutely amazing. Maybe add that to your answer and I'll select it.

Comment: Sure thing. Glad it helped.

Comment: I just got that error, but I already have this line in my setup script: `"dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"]`.  Frustratingly, it seems like every time I revisit this script some time has elapsed, it comes up with another random missing dll, although I was able to run py2exe without numpy-atlas.dll the time before and I haven't made significant changes to my application's dependencies.  Does anyone else have a similar experience?  I ruled out PyInstaller previously because it didn't play nice with Canopy Python, but maybe I should try again...

Comment: `"dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"]` excludes only the MSVCP90.dll. You have to add others you want to exclude yourself.

Comment: Excluding the .dll doesn't seem like a solution, I would think that this .dll is needed (at least in my case). For me, this setup script was working perfectly fine until I re-installed Python (previously used python(x,y) now using Anaconda, but still v2.7.x).

Answer (score 17):

This is what worked for me.
I found the dll: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numpy-atlas.dll
and copied it to the same folder that has the setup.py

Comment: Can't confirm, but sounds legit.

Comment: CAN confirm. The accepted answer didn't work. This one did. I ran into this error after upgrading to numpy 1.11.

Comment: Atlas is not a requirement for numpy, so this will not work for all users.

Comment: @bremen_matt The question explicitly says that numpy_atlas is missing so the answer is correct.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same problem. After a little testing, appending `numpy.core` directory to `sys.path` seemed to work.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

import numpy
import os
import sys

# add any numpy directory containing a dll file to sys.path
def numpy_dll_paths_fix():
    paths = set()
    np_path = numpy.__path__[0]
    for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(np_path):
        for item in filenames:
            if item.endswith('.dll'):
                paths.add(dirpath)

    sys.path.append(*list(paths))

numpy_dll_paths_fix()
setup(...)
```

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: Worked for me 3!

Comment: This worked fine and has the advantage of not requiring to manually copy the dll to the applicaton folder.